# Upload file as octet-stream using RestSharp 1.7

Tags: restsharp, octet-stream

I'm trying to upload a file as octet-stream with RestSharp 1.7 but can't get it to work.

I've tried the following approaches:

- Using restRequest.AddFile("file", documentContent, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
  This doesn't generate an octet-stream even if I specify it.
- Using restRequest.AddBody(documentContent, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
  This seems to generate an octet-stream but the content doesn't seem to be the correct byte content. This worked on v.1.6.

If anyone have a working version of uploading streaming file data for RestSharp v.1.7 it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of `documentContent`?

Comment: It's a PDF file, but can be any type of binary  data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in RestSharp v.107 according to this
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1761
and the correction here:
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/a7d2662ef95269fab1e6dac2ef2ad3003c5c1e85

The solution for now is to use the following:

```
restRequest.AddParameter(new BodyParameter("", byteArrayContent, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, DataFormat.Binary));
```